# How would I go about setting up NodeJS on my Bluehost hosting account?

Tags: web-hosting, node.js

I like using NodeJS and I've gotten OK at it. Currently I'm paying Heroku to host my NodeJS apps, but I've also have a nice hosting account on Bluehost for a while.

However, Bluehost by default, doesn't run my NodeJS apps. They simply don't offer the environment to be installed on their systems.

I spoke to a rep from Bluehost and he said it would be possible for me to install NodeJS but he wouldn't be able to tell me how since that wasn't his job.

I don't know where to begin with this. Does anyone have any tips on how I could possibly go about installing NodeJS so I could run my NodeJS apps on my own server? That would be awesome.

EDIT

I have a full hosting account on Bluehost, i.e. with a cPanel et al. I don't see any option for NodeJS and a rep told me NodeJS is not by default installed. I would have to install it myself. I have no idea how to log in with the terminal and make this happen. I would love if you would be able to give me some direction.

Comment: It is possible even without root access. Follow [link](https://ferugi.com/blog/nodejs-on-godaddy-shared-cpanel/) to see how. Another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24777750/how-to-host-a-node-js-application-in-shared-hosting/27391738) to get node running

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have a VPS or dedicated server with Bluehost then you will not be able to install it. This requires root access and they will not likely install it on a shared hosting platform.

If you do have a vps/dedi then this like should show you how to set it up, but its not supported by cpanel.

https://www.otherdata.com/blog/installing-nodejs-grunt-and-bower-cpanel-and-centos-or-cloudlinux

Comment: I have a PLUS account http://www.bluehost.com/shared

Comment: That is shared hosting you will need a VPS/Dedicated hosting to run it.

Comment: Is the root access only required for the NodeJS installation? If so, root shouldn't be necessary since you can install node for an individual user like this: http://tnovelli.net/blog/blog.2011-08-27.node-npm-user-install.html

Comment: There is a possibility that might work. But more likely it will not. If you have ssh access to your hosting account and it is not a dedicated server/vps you will not actually have full shell. They provide a jail shell or restrict the shell from commands like make. You could try to ask them to build it for you but as I have worked in the hosting world they are going to just tell you to get a dedicated hosting plan,